# How to handle In Memory Data when JVM Crashes?

Tags: java, performance, io, crash, jvm

I have a scenario where I read data from multiple threads into a Java Object(eg List or Map). Another thread is reading data from this Object and popping out upon ACKnowledgement. I want to handle data loss in the Object when JVM crashes suddenly, may be due to Power Failure or Forcibly Killing Process.

I can keep data on a file but I need to minimize I/O to increase Performance.
Acceptance Criteria is **No Data Loss**

Please suggest me some Idea.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

No Data Loss = save to disk on more than one machine (the machine or data centre) could die.  This is of course the slowest option but if that is what you need....

An alternative is to replicate to multiple machine in memory (There is a number of such solutions) but you will be limited by the speed of your link between data centres.

Answer (score 1):

Since your  Acceptance Criteria is **No Data Loss**, you have to consider disk persistence as one of feasible options.

You can use of below approaches.

1. Persist to `disk` on multiple nodes as suggested by **@Peter Lawrey**
2. Persist to `data stores` like `Couchbase`, `Ehcache` etc ( `NoSQL` is preferred)
3. Use distributed messaging system like `Kafka`